# Binding to the Current property of a BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindinglist

Say I have a `BindingList<Person>` where `Person` has a public string property called `Name`. Is there a way to effectively (if not directly) bind to the `Current` property (which is a `Person` object) and then index into the `Name` property?

I'm imagining a binding set up like

```
nameLabel.DataBindings.Add(
    new Binding("Text", this.myBindingListSource, "Current.Name", true));
```

or

```
nameLabel.DataBindings.Add(
    new Binding("Text", this.myBindingListSource.Current, "Name", true));
```

Both of these approaches produce runtime errors.

Currently, I am simply subscribing to the BindingList's `CurrentChanged` event and handling updates in there. This works but I would prefer the DataBinding approach if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the NestedBindingProxy class provided below, you can do

```
nameLabel.DataBindings.Add(
new Binding("Text", new NestedBindingProxy(this.myBindingListSource, "Current.Name"), true));
```

Below is the c# code for NestedBindingProxy. The problem with WinForms data binding is it doesn't detect value changes when you use a navigation path that contains multiple properties. WPF does this though. So I created the class NestedBindingProxy that does the change detection and it exposes a property called "Value" that the windows binding can bind too. Whenever any property changes in the navigation path, the notify property changed event will fire for the "Value" property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public sealed class NestedBindingProxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    class PropertyChangeListener
    {
        private readonly PropertyDescriptor _prop;
        private readonly WeakReference _prevOb = new WeakReference(null);

        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

        public PropertyChangeListener(PropertyDescriptor property)
        {
            _prop = property;
        }

        public object GetValue(object obj)
        {
            return _prop.GetValue(obj);
        }

        public void SubscribeToValueChange(object obj)
        {
            if (_prop.SupportsChangeEvents)
            {
                _prop.AddValueChanged(obj, ValueChanged);
                _prevOb.Target = obj;
            }
        }

        public void UnsubsctribeToValueChange()
        {
            var prevObj = _prevOb.Target;
            if (prevObj != null)
            {
                _prop.RemoveValueChanged(prevObj, ValueChanged);
                _prevOb.Target = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly object _source;
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _subscribers;
    private readonly List<PropertyChangeListener> _properties = new List<PropertyChangeListener>();
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchContext;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            bool hadSubscribers = _subscribers != null;
            _subscribers += value;
            bool hasSubscribers = _subscribers != null;
            if (!hadSubscribers && hasSubscribers)
            {
                ListenToPropertyChanges(true);
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            bool hadSubscribers = _subscribers != null;
            _subscribers -= value;
            bool hasSubscribers = _subscribers != null;
            if (hadSubscribers && !hasSubscribers)
            {
                ListenToPropertyChanges(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public NestedBindingProxy(object source, string nestedPropertyPath)
    {
        _synchContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _source = source;
        var propNames = nestedPropertyPath.Split('.');
        Type type = source.GetType();
        foreach (var propName in propNames)
        {
            var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)[propName];
            var propChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener(prop);
            _properties.Add(propChangeListener);
            propChangeListener.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => OnNestedPropertyChanged(propChangeListener);
            type = prop.PropertyType;
        }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            object value = _source;
            foreach (var prop in _properties)
            {
                value = prop.GetValue(value);
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    private void ListenToPropertyChanges(bool subscribe)
    {
        if (subscribe)
        {
            object value = _source;
            foreach (var prop in _properties)
            {
                prop.SubscribeToValueChange(value);
                value = prop.GetValue(value);
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var prop in _properties)
            {
                prop.UnsubsctribeToValueChange();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnNestedPropertyChanged(PropertyChangeListener changedProperty)
    {
        ListenToPropertyChanges(false);
        ListenToPropertyChanges(true);
        var subscribers = _subscribers;
        if (subscribers != null)
        {
            if (_synchContext != SynchronizationContext.Current)
            {
                _synchContext.Post(delegate { subscribers(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value")); }, null);
            }
            else
            {
                subscribers(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Text", myBindingListSource, "Current");
bind.Format += (s,e) => {
    e.Value = e.Value == null ? "" : ((Person)e.Value).Name;
};
nameLabel.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

I haven't tested it but it should work and I've been waiting for the feedback from you.

Comment: It is producing a runtime error saying I can't bind to `Current`. I fear I might be trying to force the BindingList to do something it isn't meant to do. Thank you though! I like this `Format` property.

Comment: @chessofnerd you talked about `BindingList` but `BindingList` doesn't have a `Current` property, so how could you bind a non-existing property? I thought you talked about a `BindingSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this by accident (four years after the original post), and after a quick read, I find that the accepted answer appears to be really over-engineered in respect to the OP's question.

I use this approach, and have posted an answer here to (hopefully) help anyone else who has the same problem.

The following should work (if infact `this.myBindingListSource` implements [IBindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx))

I would just create a [binding source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap my binding list (in my Form/View)
`BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(this.myBindingListSource, string.Empty);`

And then just bind to the binding source like this:
`nameLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSource, "Name"));`

I think the OP's original code didn't work because there is no member called 'Current' on a BindingList (unless the OP has some sort of specialised type not mentioned).